# How to read the color of a cell in Google sheets

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm using the Python Google Sheets API, and I'd like to read the color of an individual cell. I've read the docs, but I could only find info on how to retrieve the text from cell, not the color formatting.

Comment: Have you looked into Gspread [https://github.com/burnash/gspread]  module for Python?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [Method: spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get) to get the color of a specific cell.

Just pass the `spreadsheetId` and make sure you set to **true** the `includeGridData` parameter.

For example, this picture specifying the range B1.

[image]

By using this spreadsheets.get, you will get here a result of `"backgroundColor": {"green": 1}`, and not only the background color, you will also get here the `fontFamily`, `fontSize` and if it is `bold`, `italic`, `strikethrough` or `underline`.

You can try it by creating a spreadsheet, then follow the picture above.

Here is the request that I use.

```
GET https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/YOUR_SPREADSHEET_ID?includeGridData=true&ranges=B1&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Answer (score 0):

With **java**:

```
 List<String> ranges = new ArrayList<>();
            ranges.add("LinksToSearch!D2:D");
            var request = sheetService.spreadsheets().get(SheetsID);
            request.setRanges(ranges);
            request.setIncludeGridData(true);
            var response = request.execute();
            System.out.println(response); //Look at the response
```

I did not find any resource regarding how to parse it with the given google sheet API methods, so I converted the response to a JSONObject and parsed it myself, respectively to each row: (I only inspect 1 column)

```
JSONArray jObj = new JSONArray(response.get("sheets").toString());
    jObj = jObj.getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("rowData");
    System.out.println(jObj.toString()); //All rows as an object

    for (int i = 0; i < jObj.length(); i++) {
        System.out.println(
                jObj.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("values").getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("effectiveFormat").
                        getJSONObject("backgroundColor"));
    }
```