# Setting background colour of cell based on another cell's background colour

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[image: Cells]

I have the sheet shown in the above image and would like to do the following: for the cells in the range B2:B21 and D2:D21 I would like to set each cell's background colour to the background colour of their right neighbour. So, for example, the background colour of B3 should be the same as the colour of C3; the background colour of D14 should be the same as the colour of E14 and so on. Is this possible using Google Sheet's formulas, conditional formatting, or must I add a script to do this, and if so, how?

Comment: You want A and B to have the same background colour as C?

Comment: @James I believe OP wants B and D to have the same color as C and E respectively.

Comment: Just as TheMaster said, I want a cell's background colour to the same as the background colour of its right neighbour. So for each cell in column B that would be a cell in column C, and for D it would be E etc. @JamesD

Comment: How about [`getBackground()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getbackground) and [`getBackgrounds()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getbackgrounds)? You can get these properties by using the [`Method: spreadsheets.get`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get). Use the "Try It!" and provide the `spreadsheetId` to play around with this method. Check [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41981911/how-to-read-the-color-of-a-cell-in-google-sheets?rq=1) for an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try this:

```
function changeBackgroundColor() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var cRange = sheet.getRange("C2:C21");
  var cbgColors = cRange.getBackgrounds();
  var bRange = sheet.getRange("B2:B21");
  bRange.setBackgrounds(cbgColors);
  var eRange = sheet.getRange("E2:E21");
  var ebgColors = eRange.getBackgrounds();
  var dRange = sheet.getRange("D2:D21");
  dRange.setBackgrounds(ebgColors);
}
```